# Pass the whole roi's cloud to use it in plot_metrics()?

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to create a custom `plot_metrics` function that calculates a series of metrics from the Canopy Heigh Model (CHM) of the points clipped from a `catalog`.

```
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
ctg <- readLAScatalog(LASfile, filter = "-keep_random_fraction 0.5") # In my case there are many LAS files

shpfile <- system.file("extdata", "efi_plot.shp", package="lidR")
inventory <- sf::st_read(shpfile, quiet = TRUE)

my_function = function(data) {
  las = LAS(data, LASheader(data))
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  
  #---------------------
  las  <- filter_poi(las, Z > 2)
  chm <- raster(rasterize_canopy(las, res = 0.5, p2r(0.2)))
  
  max.v = max(values(chm)[complete.cases(values(chm))]) # In my case the metrics are more complex, 
  sd.v = sd(values(chm)[complete.cases(values(chm))])   # but for the sake of the example this will work
  
  metrics = list( max.v, sd.v)
  names(metrics) = c("Hmax", "Hsd")

  return(metrics)
}

my_metrics= plot_metrics(ctg, ~my_function(data), inventory, radius = 9)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in LAS(data, LASheader(data)) : 
Invalid parameter data in constructor.
```

How can I indicate that for each of the `rois` created it should apply the given function?

Answer (score 0):

The way around that I found is to pass all charactheristics of the cloud and re-make the cloud. It looks like this:

```
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
ctg <- readLAScatalog(LASfile, filter = "-keep_random_fraction 0.5") # In my case there are many LAS files

shpfile <- system.file("extdata", "efi_plot.shp", package="lidR")
inventory <- sf::st_read(shpfile, quiet = TRUE)

my_function = function(X,Y,Z,
                       Intensity,
                       ReturnNumber,
                       NumberOfReturns,
                       ScanDirectionFlag,
                       EdgeOfFlightline,
                       Classification,
                       Synthetic_flag,
                       Keypoint_flag,
                       Withheld_flag,
                       ScanAngleRank,
                       UserData,
                       PointSourceID) {
  
  
  # Read in ROI cloud
  #---------------------
  data = data.frame(X                 =   X,
                    Y                 =   Y,
                    Z                 =   Z,
                    Intensity         =   Intensity,
                    ReturnNumber      =   ReturnNumber,
                    NumberOfReturns   =   NumberOfReturns,
                    ScanDirectionFlag =   ScanDirectionFlag,
                    EdgeOfFlightline  =   EdgeOfFlightline,
                    Classification    =   Classification,
                    Synthetic_flag    =   Synthetic_flag,
                    Keypoint_flag     =   Keypoint_flag,
                    Withheld_flag     =   Withheld_flag,
                    ScanAngleRank     =   ScanAngleRank,
                    UserData          =   UserData,
                    PointSourceID     =   PointSourceID
                    )
  
  las = LAS(data, LASheader(data))
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  
  #---------------------
  las  <- filter_poi(las, Z > 2)
  chm <- raster(rasterize_canopy(las, res = 0.5, p2r(0.2)))
  
  max.v = max(values(chm)[complete.cases(values(chm))]) # In my case the metrics are more complex, 
  sd.v = sd(values(chm)[complete.cases(values(chm))])   # but for the sake of the example this will work
  
  metrics = list( max.v, sd.v)
  names(metrics) = c("Hmax", "Hsd")
  
  return(metrics)
}

my_metrics= plot_metrics(ctg, ~my_function(
  X                 =   X,
  Y                 =   Y,
  Z                 =   Z,
  Intensity         =   Intensity,
  ReturnNumber      =   ReturnNumber,
  NumberOfReturns   =   NumberOfReturns,
  ScanDirectionFlag =   ScanDirectionFlag,
  EdgeOfFlightline  =   EdgeOfFlightline,
  Classification    =   Classification,
  Synthetic_flag    =   Synthetic_flag,
  Keypoint_flag     =   Keypoint_flag,
  Withheld_flag     =   Withheld_flag,
  ScanAngleRank     =   ScanAngleRank,
  UserData          =   UserData,
  PointSourceID     =   PointSourceID
), inventory, radius = 9)
```